# Cucumber.class error: cannot convert from class cucumber to calls runner

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, cucumber

I'm getting an error in `Cucumber.class` saying

> cannot convert from class cucumber to calls runner

Here's my code:

```
package testRunners;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
//import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;


@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features="resources/features", glue="StepDefinition")
public class Login {

}
```

Comment: Providing the stacktrace  and additional details would be helpful for potential answers

Answer (score 0):

It happens when you have `dependency mismatch` in your project. More details can be seen after digging in pom.xml. Please share it.

For now you should be knowing that `@Runwith takes something which extends ParentRunner Class`, so make sure the `Cucumber.class` that you are using here is extending `ParentRunner`.